# Fragment onResume() isn't called when using FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, onresume

I need my fragments to always call a certain function when they are the active fragment, so I put it in onResume(), but it isn't being called.

Fragment A

```
@Override
public  void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("clear state", " "+clear);
    if(clear == true)
    {
        restart();
        clear = false;
        calculate();
    }
}
```

I use a FragmentPagerAdapter with a ViewPager to switch fragments

```
public class ScoutingFragSingle extends FragmentPagerAdapter{


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    switch(index){
    case 0:
        TeamsFragment teamsFragment = new TeamsFragment();
        data.putInt("current_page", index+1);
        teamsFragment.setArguments(data);
        return teamsFragment;
    case 1:

        data.putInt("current_page", index+1);
        data.putInt("matchId", matchNum);
        aFragment.setArguments(data);
        return aFragment;
```

So how would I make the fragments call their onResume()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem while ago.

Create a new interface and implement it by both of your `Fragment`s:

```
public interface OnPageSelectedListener {
    void onPageSelected();
}
```

In parent activity implement `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` and call `Fragment` method like this:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int i) {
    OnPageSelectedListener fragment = (OnPageSelectedListener ((PlaceListPagerAdapter)pager.getAdapter()).getFragment(i);
    fragment.onPageSelected();
}
```

PS: Name of the new interface and its method is a bit confusing, so be careful or change it.

Answer (score 3):

Override [Fragment.setUserVisibleHint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint%28boolean%29). When `setUserVisibleHint` is `true` call same logic you use for `onResume`.

You can see when `FragmentPagerAdapter` calls `setUserVisibleHint` in [instantiateItem](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.android/support-v4/r7/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.java#102) and [setPrimaryItem](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.android/support-v4/r7/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.java#128). Applicable to *android* since 4.2.1 and *support-v4*.