# Fragment in ViewPager returns empty object onResume

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, oncreate, fragmentpageradapter

I use a FragmentPagerAdapter to switch from fragments. I need some functions to be called when a fragmentswitch is made and had some troubles with OnPause and OnResume, so as suggested by [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17929362/1397997) question I have implemented an interface OnPageSelectListener :

```
public interface OnPageSelectListener {
    void onPageSelected();
    void onPageNotVisible();
}
```

It calls the function OnPageSelected whenever this page comes to the foreground. Works nice, except that I want to call a function on my adapter. I thought that would work, except that my adapter returns NULL all the times (even though it is initialized and data is loaded in my listview as prefered).

```
    public class AfterCheckFragment extends Fragment implements OnPageSelectListener{


        private   ListView listView;
        private List<Check> checkList;
        private CheckListAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_check, container, false);

        System.out.println("VIEW create  called");

//(.. some other stuff, not relevant for question..)

        //initializing the adapter
          listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        adapter = new CheckListAdapter(checkList,getActivity(),trainPosition);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.handleButtonVisibility();
        return view;

    }
@Override
    public void onPageSelected() {
        if(this.adapter != null) {
            System.out.println("adapter not null");
            this.adapter.checkForActive();
        }else{
            System.out.println("Adapter is NULL");
        }

    }

        @Override
        public void onPageNotVisible() { //page is moved to backgroung
            System.out.println("AFTER not active any more ");
        }
    }
```

Now is my question: Why does **adapter** (or any other object in the fragment) return null when I return to my fragment? When the fragmentPager is initialized the onActivityCreate function of the fragment is called one time, but after that not any more, and the adapter return null....

Comment: The Interface requires data communications between the Fragment (AfterCheckFragment) and the inherited interface, and I don't see it. Sometimes the fragment will call a public/protected method in the Interface, which I don't see. Please post code for OnPageSelectListener at least, and maybe for the related Adapter too.

Comment: Pls post the adapter code also since you have code this.adapter.checkForActive() and you said "Why does adapter...return null..."?

Comment: I just noticed your posted code does not show FragmentPagerAdapter at all. I am saying this because the class has its own way of switching between fragments, relevant link @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html. I think the code referencing FragmentPagerAdapter may be relevant also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is why I think your `CheckListAdapter` (i'll call it `listAdapter`) is null:

1. You give the `pagerAdapter` to the `ViewPager`
2. The `ViewPager` asks the `pagerAdapter` for a new `Fragment`
3. The `ViewPager` tells the `FragmentManager` to use it
4. `onPageSelected` gets called
5. You try and use `listAdapter`. It hasn't been initialized yet at this point. (NPE)
6. The `FragmentManager` drags the Fragment through all its stages.
7. `onCreateView` gets called. Your `listAdapter` is created.

Don't try and use internal data of a fragment outside of it. It is meant to work as a standalone unit, it won't be very good if you use it differently. Since the fragment is initialized at a later stage, you can't use it like you intend.
You can try and do what you want to do in the fragment, rather than the `pagerAdapter`, or write a method in the hosting `Activity` and call it from the fragment when ready, or even launch an event.

Answer (score 3):

you have to call the onPageSelected() after initialization of the adapter and setAdapter() otherwise adapter will return null always

Answer (score 2):

`ViewPager` will create and destroy fragments as the user changes pages (see `ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit()`).  So `onActivityCreated()` is only called on the fragment when it is being restored or set up for the first time.  Hence, fragments can be created without ever having `onActivityCreated()` called.

Instead of `onActivityCreated()`, I would recommend overriding `onViewCreated()` and setting up your adapter there.  No fragment can be displayed without having a view created, so this is a good place to do that kind of stuff.

If you have your `OnPageSelectListener` logic working, that's good.  I found the best way to know when your fragment is actually in front of the user is by overriding `setPrimaryItem()` in the `FragmentPagerAdapter`.  Getting the page out of view event is a little trickier, since you have to keep a reference to the fragment from the previous `setPrimaryItem()` call.

Comment: Hi Kris, Thanks for your answer. I implemented the initiation in the onViewCreated as you suggest (although I never had problems in using onActivityCreated) but also onViewCreate is only called when the viewpager is created. And still every time the pager returns null if I return to the view....

Comment: Could you please post more code? I did a test app similar to yours and I didn't have any problem.  The view for page 2 is created offscreen while user views page 1, so when user scrolls and  `OnPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(2)` is called, view has already been created, so... no issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is because Viewpager calls OnpageSelected way before Fragments in oncreateView()/onActivityCreated() is called .

The best way for you is to inflate your views in the constructor  of the Fragment and set the Adapters.

Or

Use a member variable to store  whether the Fragment is active or not. And use the variable in oncreateview() to call function on your adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a `viewpager.addOnPageChangeListener`, in you pager , after setting its adapter and the `setOffscreenPageLimit()` instead of `implements` it on your fragment?

Heres a sample code:

```
viewpager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
       if(position == 1){  // if you want the second page, for example
           //Your code here
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
});
```

*Make it in your `Activity`, where you setup your `ViewPager`, of course.*

Answer (score 1):

for me i had to call this on my viewpager:

```
myViewPager.setSaveFromParentEnabled(false);
```